# Unexpected behaviour of MediaPlayer Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to stream mp3 file from the internet. App successfully started but showing unexpected behavior. The playback doesn't play sound, the play button doesn't changes its icon. The playback stops after showing "please wait message" when it is expected to play the file on clicking the play icon.

Here's my code:

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import dyanamitechetan.vusikview.VusikView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener, MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

    ImageButton imageButton;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    TextView textView;

    VusikView musicView;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int mediaFileLength;
    int realTimeLength;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        musicView = findViewById(R.id.musicView);

        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        seekBar.setMax(99);
        seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
                    int playPosition = (mediaFileLength/100)*seekBar.getProgress();
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPosition);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        imageButton = findViewById(R.id.btn_play_pause);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

                AsyncTask<String,String,String>mp3Play = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute(){
                        mDialog.setMessage("Please wait");
                        mDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                        try {
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(strings[0]);
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex){

                        }
                        return "";
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                        mediaFileLength = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                        realTimeLength = mediaFileLength;
                        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                        } else {
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                            imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                        }
                        updateSeekBar();
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                };

                mp3Play.execute("https://soundcloud.com/theastonshuffle/nasa-feat-kanye-west-santogold-lykke-li-gifted-aston-shuffle-long-mix");

                musicView.start();
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

    }

    private void updateSeekBar() {
        seekBar.setProgress((int)((float)mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaFileLength*100));

        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            Runnable updater = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateSeekBar();
                    realTimeLength-=1000;
                    textView.setText(String.format("%d:%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(realTimeLength),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(realTimeLength) -
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(realTimeLength))));
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(updater,1000);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {
        seekBar.setSecondaryProgress(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

        imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
        musicView.stopNotesFall();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <dyanamitechetan.vusikview.VusikView
        android:id="@+id/musicView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTimer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_below="@id/textTimer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_play_pause"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play"/>

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/btn_play_pause"
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you APP connect Internet ？
please check manifest is add internet permission
You can use the `mediaplay.setdataSource (url);`method directly to load
And set`mediaplay.prepareAsync ();` use asynchronous method to load music
No need to use AsyncTask